# call libraries from model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, libraries, error-logging

I'm trying to call a library from model in codeigniter but doesn't want to fire and I don't really know how to debug it, I have been trying to use codeigniters default logging method but doesn't show anything. My code looks as it follows.

```
class Model_products extends CI_Model{


    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('ApiClient');
        log_message('error', $this->load->library('ApiClient'));

}       
}

/application/libraries/ApiClient.php

libary final class ApiClient
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot name a library **ApiClient** - class names should follow the CI naming convention (which is identical to [ucfirst()](http://php.net/ucfirst)) and when loading anything in CI you need to load it with lowercase naming.

Naming is the key.

Your file should be named `Apiclient.php` (libraries has the first letter in uppercase in the filenames, models, views and controller are all lowercase filenaming).

Your class definition should reflect this also:

```
class Apiclient
{
  ...
}
```

And when using the CI instance to load the library, you need to load it with lowercase naming:

```
$this->load->library('apiclient');
```

Comment: hi I made those changes but unfortunately after all no results. And the debugger shows me nothing what would help. Just blank screen

Comment: Your Apiclient library probably fails and that's why the log doesn't show you anything. Check your Apache error log.

Comment: yes I been taking a look and it shows the following Call to private from context 'CI_Loader' /Loader.php on line 1099. But I found another approach to include directly my api class include(APPPATH.'libraries/ApiClient.php'); but I don't know if is the best way to do it or not

Answer (score 0):

You miss a semicolon at the end of your line `$this->load->library('ApiClient')`. Could this be it?